# Replace tzitzis on Tallis with no broken strings? just because the new strings are nicer?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tallit-gadol

My friend gave me his tallis with a set of new strings to tie. however, I was once told that its better not to remove tzitzis from a garment unless the strings actually need to be replaced.

Can I replace the strings on this tallis with the new thicker/nicer stings, even the the existing strings are mostly fine?

(only 1 sting on 1 corner is broken below the bottom knot with 1 inch still remaining)

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate: https://dinonline.org/2019/11/04/cutting-tzizit-from-talis/

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Janos and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?